Relative distribution of primes among consecutive squares
For each prime $p,$ define $n_p>0; {n_p}^2$ is the greatest square integer $\leq p,$ so that ${n_p}^2 \leq p < (n_p + 1)^2.$ [Now note that $(n_p + 1)^2-1-{n_p}^2 = 2n_p $]. Is $S:= \left\{ \frac{p-{n_p}^2}{2n_p}: p \text{ is prime} \right\} $ a dense subset of or equidistributed sequence in $[0,1]?$
I am aware that Lengendre's conjecture is an open problem, which sort of suggests to me that the equidistributed part of the question is likely very difficult. However, I wonder if any (elementary or otherwise) number theory techniques can be used to answer the density part.
